# How to check do variable is initialized

Tags: php, variables

My example

```
<?php
if(something){
$message = "set";
}

echo $message; // but I can get error that variable is not unidentified ?>
```

My question how to check do variable is initialized to not get error "unidentified variable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like

```
$message = NULL;
if(something){
$message = "set";
}

if($message){
   echo $message;
}
```

[**Codepad**](http://codepad.org/OUMRhhMQ)

or check that variable is set by  `isset`

```
echo isset($var)?$var:'';
```

Comment: thanks, but if I use in 1 if header("location: index.php"); how to save message variable ? it's possible ?

Comment: you can do this by either Session or by `header("location: index.php?message=".$message);`

Comment: iin second condition you can set the message var again by getting the data form url by `$message = $_GET['message']`

Comment: @TomasLietuva yup ...session would be better ... )

Answer (score 1):

Use isset (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
$message = "not set";

if (isset($var)) {
    $message = "set";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest would be the isset function:

```
if (isset($somethink)) {
    $messege = "set";
} else {
    $message = "";
}
```

or

```
$message = (isset($somthink)) ? "set" : "";
```

But, note that isset checks whether the variable is defined and is not null.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(something){
    $message = "set";
}
echo isset($message)?$message:'';//this will not give error now

?>
```